# is_unique codeigniter issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am using Ver: 2.1.0 and I am having the following issue when I use is_unique within my form_validation function:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userName', 'User Name', 'trim|required|is_unique["users.userName"]|xss_clean|');
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

But my table structure is correct and the db is connecting:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the folks have provided legit answers. One small issue I see that (CI will probably clean up...) but kill the last bar (|) as well in your rules string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table name is wrong. You are quering "users table instead of users which is caused by is_unique["users.userName"] use is_unique[users.userName] instead.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes from `is_unique["users.userName"]`. It's messing up the query!

Refer to the table from this page to see the example:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference